# Unresolved reference `flask_sqlachemy` in PyCharm with pipenv

Tags: python, flask, pycharm, flask-sqlalchemy

I use PyCharm when working with my python project. I also use `pipenv` as my packaging tool. There is no problem when I install `flask==1.1.1` and `Flask-RESTPlus==0.13.0` using `pipenv`. But, when I install `Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.4.1` and add `from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy`, there is `unresolved reference`. When I check my project interpreter, I have used the `pipenv` environment. What is the problem?

[image]

Comment: What do you get if you run `/pip freeze` in your env?

Comment: please provide the full error log, so other can help fully. also check if pipenv is set in your pycharm or not

Comment: Do you have an error on runtime?

Comment: No. If I run my project there is no error. But why the `unresolved reference` is shown in my program?